# Is this possible through iCloud, or would a private server be a necessity?

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, collaboration

I'm trying to come up with an app that my brother was telling me about, but I'm not sure if it can be done or not.

Basically I want to have a list, that is visible through multiple devices. I want any of these devices to be able to edit/add to the list as well.

I was hoping I could use iCloud to make a word document that is basically just a list, but also be able to add collaborators.  I know this is possible through the iCloud website, but is it available to developers?

Thanks

Comment: You can write this using CloudKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is yes, so long as the app doesn't require a bunch of backend logic. But that will be for you to decide. Here is a great overview of what can be done:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/134694/cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started

Good Luck!